# How do I apply np.random.multivariate_normal on list of vectors and covariance matrices?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have N M-dimensional vectors. i.e. I have a (N, M) dimensional numpy array, let's call it "mean".

I also have N M-by-M dimensional covariance matrices. i.e. I have a (N, M, M) dimensional numpy array, let's call it "covs".

Here's the question: How do I efficiently generate N random vectors, distributed according to the N mean vectors and N covariance matrices? In other words, how do I implement the following function efficiently?

```
def GenRandVar(mean, covs):
    rand_result = []
    for m, c in zip(mean, covs}:
        rand_result.append(np.random.multivariate_normal(m, c))
return np.array(rand_result)
```

Comment: What inputs (shape etc) does `np.random.multivariate_normal` accept?

Comment: It accepts a M-dimensional array and a M times M dimensional array. It generates a random M-dimensional array, distributed according to mean vector given as the first argument and covariance matrix given by the second array. Please see https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.multivariate_normal.html for details.

Comment: Yes, I know where to find the docs, but want you to discuss why you can't adapt your arrays to that requirement.  Have you tried anything besides this loop?

Comment: I can generate multiple samples with multivariate_normal  if I want them to follow the same mean vector and the same covariance matrix. However I want every sample to follow different mean vectors and different covariance matrices. The N M-dimensional vectors and N M-by-M dimensional covariance matrices are all distinct. This is where I am having troubles. I don't know how to do it beyond implementing a for loop. It is my understanding that for loop like this is non-pythonic? I tried to put my (N, M) array and (N, M, M) array directly in np.random.multivariate_normal and it doesn't work.

Comment: A loop is very pythonic.  `for ...` is normal python structure.  Code can be faster if the loop is performed in compiled numpy functions or methods.  But if `np.random.multivariate_normal` can't be called with your arrays, or with them reshaped, you may have to do the loop.  There's more to calling something "pythonic" or "numpyonic" or "vectorized" than just avoiding loops.

Comment: Typically `np.random` functions are used to generate many (`size`) random variables.  For just one random sample the python `random` functions are faster, though in this case that's not an option.  In general if you need the kind of distribution independence that the functions don't provide, you do have to iterate.